# Gnuplot: plotting the differences between two matrices

Tags: gnuplot

I have two files `file1.dat` and `file2.dat` that each contain a matrix (say, F1 and F2, respectively) that agree in dimensions (i.e. they're both `m x n` matrices). I know how to use gnuplot to plot either of them (`splot "file1.dat" matrix` for instance), but how do I instruct gnuplot to plot F1-F2?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, (to my knowledge) there is no way to plot information from multiple files using gnuplot.  The solution is to write a simple script (in your favorite language) that takes the two files as input and writes the difference as output... Then you could do:

```
splot "<myscript file1.dat file2.dat" matrix ...
```

I'm sure that with enough coaxing, using `set table` and shell magic, I could come up with a hack to do what you want (having gnuplot output multiple datafiles, issuing shell commands to paste the datafiles together ...), but in the end, writing your own script would be a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using a bit of awk in gnuplot.

```
set terminal postscript enhanced colour
set output 'matrixdiff.eps'

unset key 
splot "<awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)a[FNR,i]=$i;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)$i=a[FNR,i]-$i;print}' mat1 mat2" matrix
```

`mat1` and `mat2` are the matrix files you want to plot.  The awk script is from [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1085892).

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and the records, there is a **gnuplot-only** solution without getting too complicated, however, most likely less efficient than with external tools.
It's going via data stored in a long string. For smaller matrices this still should be ok. With gnuplot 4.6.0 I have seen a limit of about approx. 38'000 characters, which corresponds to a 64x64 matrix with 6 digit numbers. For gnuplot 5.4, I tested only until a 200x200 matrix without problems (but it will take some time to plot).

**Data:**

`SO10091196_1.dat`

```
10  11  12  13
24  25  26  27
38  39  40  41
```

`SO10091196_2.dat`

```
10  10  10  10
20  20  20  20
30  30  30  30
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.1, June 2015)

```
### plot the difference of two matrices
reset

FILE1 = "SO10091196_1.dat"
FILE2 = "SO10091196_2.dat"

mat2 = ''
stats FILE2 matrix u (cols=$1+1,rows=$2+1,mat2=mat2.sprintf(" %g",$3),0) nooutput

set view map
set xrange [-0.5:cols-0.5]
set yrange [-0.5:rows-0.5]

splot FILE1 matrix u 1:2:($3-real(word(mat2,int($2*cols+1+$1)))) w image
### end of script
```

For gnuplot>=4.4.0 (March 2010) and <=5.0.0 you need to replace the `stats` line with:

```
cols = rows = 0
set term unknown
    plot FILE2 matrix u (cols=$1+1,rows=$2+1,mat2=mat2.sprintf(" %g",$3))
set term wxt   # or your default terminal
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Addition:**

A version for gnuplot>=5.2.0 using an array which is much faster than the string approach from above and no size limitations (tested only until 500x500 array).

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### plot the difference of two matrices
reset

FILE1 = "SO10091196_1.dat"
FILE2 = "SO10091196_2.dat"

M = 0   # number of rows, 0 if unknown
N = 0   # number of cols, 0 if unknown
if (!M || !N) {
    stats FILE2 u 0 nooutput   # get number of rows and cols
    M = STATS_records
    N = STATS_columns
}

array M2[M*N]
stats FILE2 matrix u (M2[int($2*N+$1+1)] = $3) nooutput   # put values into array

set view map
set xrange [-0.5:N-0.5]
set yrange [-0.5:M-0.5]

splot FILE1 matrix u 1:2:($3-M2[int($2*N+$1+1)]) w image
### end of script
```